# Find Covariance between dataframes ignoring NA

Tags: r, dataframe, na, covariance

I have a data frame where each column is a time series. I would like to find the correlation between one of the columns and the rest of the data frame. The problem is, the rest of the data frame contains NAs. Is there a succint way to find all these covariances ignoring NAs in each column?

I could only find a way to do this using a for loop, which is not ideal.
Here is a sample data

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18628, 18629, 18630, 18631, 
18632, 18633, 18634, 18635, 18636, 18637), class = "Date"), X1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1.16092168555067, 0.591202293337843, -0.279052669225263, 
-0.780435476613128, -0.852870619718068, -0.708611614262357), 
    X2 = c(NA, NA, -0.222767493777229, 1.50328295132467, 0.934670132217215, 
    1.37678188537077, 0.343280062984192, 1.23279081824003, -1.08074586121729, 
    0.208120194894818), X3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.72057538716556, 
    1.37803710718683, 1.24717457500191, -0.00930256437131184, 
    0.491423553538728), X4 = c(1.15304498847709, -0.154433520961086, 
    -0.361871232243227, -0.981985961481073, 0.596667113671836, 
    -0.0960746707238904, -1.53792603627306, 1.00296956396233, 
    0.128292175597246, -1.12744557711187)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Using this data, I would like to obtain a vector with the covariances between x1 and x4, removing all NAs in x1, then covariance between x2 and x4, removing all NAs in x2, and so on. I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the argument `use = complete` in the function `cov()` to ignore the NAs values (other options are available as well). This might be useful for you (the example computes the var-cov matrix using your dataframe.

```r
aa = structure(list(Date = structure(c(18628, 18629, 18630, 18631, 
18632, 18633, 18634, 18635, 18636, 18637), class = "Date"), X1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1.16092168555067, 0.591202293337843, -0.279052669225263, 
-0.780435476613128, -0.852870619718068, -0.708611614262357), 
    X2 = c(NA, NA, -0.222767493777229, 1.50328295132467, 0.934670132217215, 
    1.37678188537077, 0.343280062984192, 1.23279081824003, -1.08074586121729, 
    0.208120194894818), X3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.72057538716556, 
    1.37803710718683, 1.24717457500191, -0.00930256437131184, 
    0.491423553538728), X4 = c(1.15304498847709, -0.154433520961086, 
    -0.361871232243227, -0.981985961481073, 0.596667113671836, 
    -0.0960746707238904, -1.53792603627306, 1.00296956396233, 
    0.128292175597246, -1.12744557711187)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

cov(aa[, -1], use = 'complete')

            X1        X2           X3           X4
X1  0.36049927 0.3436964  0.319734021 -0.095666285
X2  0.34369636 0.9697499  0.620778723  0.220293460
X3  0.31973402 0.6207787  0.498663689 -0.003728815
X4 -0.09566628 0.2202935 -0.003728815  1.034121716
```

**Edit** for pairwise complete obs `use = 'pairwise.complete.obs'`

```
cov(aa[, -1], use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')

          X1         X2           X3           X4
X1 0.6975825 0.41039379  0.319734021  0.164427330
X2 0.4103938 0.80303434  0.620778723  0.091645141
X3 0.3197340 0.62077872  0.498663689 -0.003728815
X4 0.1644273 0.09164514 -0.003728815  0.809167748

# Test using aa[5:10, 2] vs aa[5:10, 5]
cov(aa[5:10, 2], aa[5:10, 5])
[1] 0.1644273
```

Comment: This is not quite what I want, since it is removing all rows with NAs. From my example, I want to remove 4 rows from X1, 2 rows from X2, 5 rows from X3 and then find the correlation with and appropriate sized X4 (removing 4 rows when find cov with X1, 2 rows with X2 and so on)

Comment: Then I think use = pairwise.complete.obs' but I would give also a look at this http://bwlewis.github.io/covar/missing.html